# Perfomance in Position

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I need to find the position of elements in `list` that are present in `close`. These are both 2D lists. The code is simple but not as efficient as I want:

```
 list = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {50000, 2}];
 close = RandomSample[list, 500];
 Position[list, #] & /@ close // AbsoluteTiming
```

This takes about 0.76 seconds to complete, Is there a way to make it more efficient? For a better comparison with actual data,`list` should have 250000 elements and `close` 50000.

Comment: Are `list` and `close` sorted? What kind of numbers do they contain?

Comment: `list` is about 250000 tuples, `{x,y}`, where `x` and `y` are real numbers. `close` is about 50000.

Comment: Start you question with something like `list=RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 15000, WorkingPrecision -> 30]`. It would restrict the domain of your question and you will get better tailored answers.

Comment: If `close` is a subset of `list`, maybe `nF=Nearest[list->"Index"]; nF/@close`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest):

```
list=RandomReal[10, {250000,2}];
close=RandomSample[list, 50000];

nf = Nearest[close->"Index"];
Flatten @ nf[list, {1, 0}]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.113003, Null}

*Update*

I think I got it backward, based on your example. Just flip `close` and `list`:

```
list=RandomReal[10, {250000,2}];
close=RandomSample[list, 50000];

nf = Nearest[list->"Index"];
Flatten @ nf[close, {1, 0}]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.052, Null}

Comment: This is perfect. can you elaborate little bit about why the huge increase in performance? Im assuming because I try to use position on every element of `close`, but somehow nearest bypasses this?

Comment: @GiovanniBaez Nearest creates a specialized data structure (octree) so that it can quickly find the nearest element.

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomReal[1, {25000, 2}];
close =Join [RandomReal[1, {2000, 2}], RandomSample[list, 3000]];
nF = Nearest[list -> "Index"];
res1 = nF @ Intersection[list, close];// RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0052

versus

```
res2 = Position[list, #] & /@ Intersection[list, close] ; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 2.53

Note: Use `Automatic` in place of `"Index"` for versions older than 10+.

Comment: ... use `close` in place of `Intersection[list, close]` if `close` is a subset of `list`.

Comment: `NearestFunctions` are listable, so `res1 = nF[Intersection[list, close]];` is a bit faster.

Comment: Thank you @Henrik. I will update with your suggestion.